# Show GUI when running nrniv?

Tags: neuroscience, biological-neural-network, neuron-simulator

How do you open the GUI when running NEURON simulator using the nrniv command?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console type in:

```
nrnmainmenu()
```

And, if using the --python flag:

```
h.nrnmainmenu()
```